# How to avoid losing type bounds during type projection

Tags: scala, type-projection

I had problem with writing proxy that could take and pass abstract type members from its originator.

```
trait Holder[A[_]] {
  type I
  type Y <: A[I]
}

trait Proxy[A[_], H <: Holder[A]] extends Holder[A] {
  override type I = H#I
  override type Y = H#Y
}
```

I got the error:

```
error: overriding type Y in trait Holder with bounds <: A[Proxy.this.I];
 type Y has incompatible type
  override type Y = H#Y
                ^
one error found
```

Is that a fundamental scala restriction, or could it be circumvented somehow?

Comment: I think you meant `override type Y = A[I]`?

Comment: Nope. I'd like to pass types from originator object to the proxy. So I could use its methods that are defined in terms of originator types

Answer (score 1):

Your definition of `Holder` means that for a specific object `h: Holder[A]`, you have `h.Y <: A[h.I]`.

But this doesn't imply `H#Y <: A[H#I]` for every `H <: Holder[A]`. I *think* it does if `A` is covariant (because you have `h.Y <: A[h.I] <: A[H#I]` and so the common supertype of all `h.Y` is `<: A[H#I]`).